# resolve #{var} in string

Tags: ruby

I have loaded a string with #{variable} references in it.  How would I resolve those variables in the string like `puts` does?

```
name="jim"
str="Hi #{name}"
puts str
```

Instead of puts, I would like to have the result available to pass as a parameter or save into a variable.

Comment: what you have done works in any string not just in puts. This code should work

Comment: How exactly have you "loaded" your string? From where?

Comment: The string is loaded from a yaml file.  The file is only changed by a developer or administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could eval it

```
name = "Patrick"

s = 'hello, #{name}'
s # => "hello, \#{name}"

# wrap the string in double quotes, making it a valid interpolatable ruby string
eval "\"#{s}\"" # => "hello, Patrick"
```

Comment: eval is overkill and potentially dangerous. If he needs it delayed, he could use a method or lambda, but eval isn't worth it

Comment: What if he loads string from a db? What would you do then, if not eval?

Comment: That is a dangerous game, and bad design, it would mean that you have strings in your DB that depend on being loaded in a certain scope in order to get resolved properly

Comment: It's dangerous, sure. But this post answers the question asked. Your downvote is unjustified (not that I care about it).

Comment: @JimDeville that's why you use [RubyCop](https://github.com/envylabs/RubyCop) to safety-check code before eval.

Comment: `eval` sucks, but so does the problem. Outside of writing a custom parser or using a different format with a parser, it’s the solution.

Comment: RubyCop doesn't look like it would stop a determined and malicious individual

Comment: eval was required ..  The string is from a internal secure yaml file.  Thank you!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Given that the OP has mentioned that eval was needed, i'd revert it, but can't. There are so many other options (convention based parsing methods, ERB, etc) that I couldn't justify using eval in this scenario

Comment: @JimDeville: how's ERB any better (in his case)?

Comment: If he has strings in a file that need to be combined with context from  his code, then it sounds like the ideal use case for templates (i.e. ERB). ERB also isn't just a blind eval.

Comment: What about `'hello, %s' % name`? It works in single quotes and dictates the exact type of variable to receive, you can pull the formatted string from a YAML file, and it does not require `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

`puts` doesn't resolve the variables. The Ruby parser does when it creates the string. if you passed `str` to any other method, it would be the same as passing 'Hi jim', since the interpolation is already done.

Comment: I edited earlier to reflect that "The Ruby parser does when it creates the string"...

Answer (score 1):

String has a format option that appears as [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25). It can be used to pass arguments into a predefined string much like interpolation does.

```
message = "Hello, %s"
for_patrick = message % "Patrick" #=> "Hello, Patrick"
for_jessie  = message % "Jessie"  #=> "Hello, Jessie"

messages = "Hello, %s and %s"
for_p_and_j = messages % ["Patrick", "Jessie"] #=> "Hello, Patrick and Jessie"
```

It may not look "Rubyish" but I believe it is the functionality you are looking for.

So, if you have a string coming in from somewhere that contains these placeholders, you can then pass in values as arguments as so:

```
method_that_gets_hello_message % "Patrick"
```

This will also allow you to only accept values you are expecting.

```
message = "I can count to %d"
message % "eleven" #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer()
```

There's a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) on Wikipedia for possible placeholders for `printf()` that should also work in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The `eval` seems to be the only solution for *this particular* task. But we can avoid this *dirty-unsafe-dishonourable* `eval` if we modify the task a bit: we can resolve not local, but **instance** variable without `eval` using [`instance_variable_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get):

```
@name = "Patrick"
@id = 2 # Test that number is ok
@a_b = "oooo" # Test that our regex can eat underscores

s = 'hello, #{name} !!#{id} ??#{a_b}'

s.gsub(/#\{(\w+)\}/) { instance_variable_get '@'+$1 }
=> "hello, Patrick !!2 ??oooo"
```

In this case you even can use any other characters instead of `#{}` (for example, `%name%` etc), by only modifying the regex a bit.

But of course, all this *smells*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the basis for a template system, which Ruby does easily if you use String's `gsub` or `sub` methods.

```
replacements = { '%greeting%' => 'Hello', '%name%' => 'Jim' }
pattern = Regexp.union(replacements.keys)
'%greeting% %name%!'.gsub(pattern, replacements)
=> "Hello Jim!"
```

You could just as easily define the key as:

```
replacements = { '#{name}' => 'Jim' }
```

and use Ruby's normal string interpolation `#{...}` but I'd recommend not reusing that. Instead use something unique.

The advantage to this is the target => replacement map can easily be put into a YAML file, or a database table, and then you can swap them out with other languages, or different user information. The sky is the limit.

The benefit to this also, is there is no evaluation involved, it's only string substitution. With a bit of creative use you can actually implement macros:

```
macros = { '%salutation%' => '%greeting% %name%' }
replacements = { '%greeting%' => 'Hello', '%name%' => 'Jim' }
macro_pattern, replacement_pattern = [macros, replacements].map{ |h| Regexp.union(h.keys) }
'%salutation%!'.gsub(macro_pattern, macros).gsub(replacement_pattern, replacements)
=> "Hello Jim!"
```