# How to store ruby blocks in db and use them?

Tags: ruby, block

Basically I want to store a Ruby Block into DB and use them.

One could ask why - reason being, i want my users to be able to post / upload a block code - which could be executed to fetch a desired result for their problem on the data we might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you don't want to store ruby blocks. You want to store code. This is easier. Just store the code as a string. And then later you can [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) that string, effectively executing the code.

Now you have to solve a hard problem: how to prevent users from posting malicious code (or how to sandbox them). But that's out of scope here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sergio. And yes - we'll be approving the code from the admin panel before system picks up the block code for evaluation.

Comment: @KannanR, about safety, in comments to [an answer to another eval-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566947/693538) people suggested [RubyCop](https://github.com/envylabs/RubyCop), which in your case may help your admins by highlighting potentialy dangerous code in the list, so they do not miss it.

Comment: If you want to [eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) and execute code submited by users, its a good idea to do some investigation on [Ruby Safe Sevels](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/taint.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, store your code as a string (the [ruby2ruby gem](http://docs.seattlerb.org/ruby2ruby/) may helps you). When you need to execute this block, retrieve it from DB, and use the "[eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)" method